# Jmeter not executing script from command line (CLI mode) but works fine with GUI mode

Tags: testing, jmeter

I wrote a script in Jmeter that is fine being executed from GUI mode but will fail when being executed from CLI mode (non-GUI)

This is the result from CLI mode:

> D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin>jmeter -n -t
> D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\homepage.jmx Creating
> summariser  Created the tree successfully using
> D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\homepage.jmx Starting
> standalone test @ Fri Mar 18 09:41:02 EET 2022 (1647589262323) Waiting
> for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port
> 4445 summary +      1 in 00:00:00 =   25.0/s Avg:     0 Min:     0
> Max:     0 Err:     1 (100.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
> summary +     19 in 00:00:05 =    4.0/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:
> 0 Err:    19 (100.00%) Active: 0 Started: 20 Finished: 20 summary =
> 20 in 00:00:05 =    4.2/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:     0 Err:    20
> (100.00%) Tidying up ...    @ Fri Mar 18 09:41:07 EET 2022
> (1647589267321) ... end of run

Why is this happening and how can i fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just running your test without storing the results and from the output it seems that all your 20 requests have failed.

I would recommend [re-running your test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) providing the path to the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) as a parameter like:

```
jmeter -n -t D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\homepage.jmx -l result.jtl
```

and then inspect the `result.jtl` file using Excel or equivalent or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it, you will see at least response code and message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I admit I am only getting to know Jmeter so there's lots of things I am figuring out but using your advice I was able to discover that there was an illegal character '/' in the script I created. All I had to do was delete it and everything worked fine after.